# Regex Comparison between two strings

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to compare strings with standard string structure.

```
string structure = Bank*Loan*1.pdf;

string name = BankAutoLoanByCustomer1.pdf;
```

How to compare name string with standard string structure? I am trying to get whether skeleton of name is same as of skeleton of structure.

Comment: You’re more looking for wild card matching than regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize [Operators.LikeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.operators.likestring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

```
bool isMatch = Operators.LikeString("BankAutoLoanByCustomer1.pdf", "Bank*Loan*1.pdf", Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It worked well. I have a question reg the performance when compared between the Operators.LikeString and Regex Which one is fast when making comparison?

Comment: @user3477335 Cannot say for sure. You'd better benchmark both methods.

Answer (score 1):

You test it like this:

```
bool matches = Regex.IsMatch(name, structure);
```

However, regex syntax is different to what you're using.

A few special characters you need:

`.` = any single character
`*` = 0 or more times
`\` = escape character: treat the next character literally, not as a special character.

So, your `structure` should be more like:

```
string structure = "Bank.*Loan.*1\\.pdf";
```

Note that you actually have to use two slashes to escape a character, because C# strings also use `\` as an escape character.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your loose criteria:

```
Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^Bank.*Loan.*1\.pdf$");
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to match Bank **anything** Loan **anything** 1.pdf?

In that case, you can use the Regex

```
Bank.*Loan.*1\.pdf
```

The period means "ANY character except newline".  The star means "0 or more times".  The \ escapes the period before **pdf**, because we want an actual period, not an "ANY character except newline".

Answer (score 0):

First you should learn how to declare strings in c# - you need to use double quotes ""

```
string structure = "Bank*Loan*1.pdf";

string name = "BankAutoLoanByCustomer1.pdf";
```

Secondly you should ask the right questions - as I see you basically want to find files in a directory that match a specific pattern and then you can use

```
Directory.GetFiles("directoryName", structure)
```